# Why calling super.finalize() is preferred when overriding finalize() method?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting SonarQube error that : "*Calling the `super.finalize()` at the end of this method implementation is highly recommended in case parent implementations must also dispose some system resources.*"

But I found that `Object` class has no implementation for [finalize](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Object.java#Object.finalize%28%29) method.

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable { }
```

So why need to call `super.finalize()`?

Comment: There might be other classes in the class heirarchy sitting between your class and `Object`

Comment: You are right, but in this case SonarQube should catch that before raising a warning !

Comment: Seriously, did you look at what sonarQube says? - **in case parent implementations must also dispose some system resources**

Comment: @egelev Say some point down the line your class heirarchy changes and your class that previously was a direct subclass of `Object` gets changed to have an intermediate superclass. If you'd simply called `super.finalize()` in the first place, you wouldn't need to go and update your `finalize()` implementation, it would just work. If you *didn't* call it, you'd have to remember to go and add the call at that point. It's safer just to always put the call there - in the grand scheme of things it won't cost you a lot but it could save you a headache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a need, it's a finalizer writing idiom that should be followed.

If, at any time in the future, you refactor your code and your class extends some other class that may have a `finalize` method, this practice will prevent strange bugs from popping up.

The idiom is

```
try {
   // Do whatever the finalization is
}
finally {
   super.finalize();
}
```

This ensures that the superclass finalizer, if there is ever a non-trivial one, will be called even if some exception is thrown (because nothing catches exceptions in finalizers, their execution simply stops).

And of course: **Avoid finalizers**. (Item 7 in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, second edition).

Comment: Ya.. +1 for the last line. *finalizers are evil* :P

Answer (score 5):

> The finalize method of class Object performs no special action; it simply returns normally. Subclasses of Object may override this definition.

Who knows, `super` class of your current class ovveriden this method.

Look where you are in the below hierarchy.

```
Object  --- no implementation 

  -- 

    -- Your Super class -- Overriden the finalize 

      -- Current class
```

Super doesn't always represent the `Object` class. There might be no of super classes in middle.

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube error clearly states as well. Please consider that the class you write might have a parent hierarchy at any point of time. Cleaning up of resources is always looked up hierarchy above for efficient cleanup. Whether or not you have a super class, usage of `super.finalize()` is  thus useful for clearing up references referred from the parent.